# Visual Studio Setup and Deployment - Installation Folder Selection

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-deployment

I have a VS2005 Setup & Deployment project and I've run into an issue that I would like assistance with.

Here is my issue:

The '**DefaultLocation**' for my application is set to '**[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyApp**'.  Now I would like the user to select what **drive** to install this application to.  I know this is accomplished through the '**Installation Folder Selection**' dialog, but I want the user to be able to select a **drive** only, **not the entire path**.

My question is how do I capture what drive the user selected from the 'Installation Folder Selection' dialog and use that drive letter to tack on to my 'DefaultLocation' variable?

*Example:*  If the user selected "M:\" from the installation folder selection dialog, I want to install to "**M:\Program Files\MyApp**" or if the user selected "E:\", then install to "**E:\Program Files\MyApp**".